# ForEach loop to close modals

Tags: javascript

I'm experimenting using arrays to open and close modals instead of having a variable for each one of them. It works for opening but not for closing. It iterates through the first one in the array but it doesn't go through the others. The specific code is in the function "closeModal.onclick" and "window.onclick".

JS:

```
  'use strict';
  const modalContent = [
    document.querySelector("#modal-or"), 
    document.querySelector("#modal-and"), 
    document.querySelector("#modal-not"), 
    document.querySelector("#modal-shortCircuit")];
  const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
  const closeModal = document.querySelector(".closeModal");

  document.querySelector("#or").onclick = function() {
    modalContent[0].setAttribute('style', 'display: block;');
  }

  document.querySelector("#and").onclick = function() {
    modalContent[1].setAttribute('style', 'display: block;');
  }

  document.querySelector("#not").onclick = function() {
    modalContent[2].setAttribute('style', 'display: block;');
  }

  document.querySelector("#shortCircuit").onclick = function() {
    modalContent[3].setAttribute('style', 'display: block;');
  }

  closeModal.onclick = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(e);
    modalContent.forEach(element => {
      element.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
    });
  }

  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target === modal) {
      modalContent.forEach(element => {
        element.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
      });
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="flexLayout">
      <div id="or">
        <div class="modal" id="modal-or">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <button class="closeModal">&times;</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="and">
        <div class="modal" id="modal-and">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <button class="closeModal">&times;</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="not">
        <div class="modal" id="modal-not">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <button class="closeModal">&times;</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="shortCircuit">
        <div class="modal" id="modal-shortCircuit">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <button class="closeModal">&times;</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #878787;
  width: 80%;
}

.closeModal {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.closeModal:hover, .closeModal:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: `querySelector` only returns the first matching element, not a collection. You need listeners on all the close buttons and will also have same issue with window listener matching target to `modal`

Comment: @charlietfl  thanks for the response. because of your feedback I looked at it with a new perspective and I was able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
  'use strict';
  const modalContent = [[document.querySelector("#or"), document.querySelector("#modal-or")], 
                        [document.querySelector("#and"), document.querySelector("#modal-and")], 
                        [document.querySelector("#not"), document.querySelector("#modal-not")], 
                        [document.querySelector("#shortCircuit"), document.querySelector("#modal-shortCircuit")]];
  const modal = document.querySelectorAll(".modal");
  const closeModal = document.querySelectorAll(".closeModal");

  modalContent[0][0].onclick = function() {
    modalContent[0][1].setAttribute('style', 'display: block;');
  }

  modalContent[1][0].onclick = function() {
    modalContent[1][1].setAttribute('style', 'display: block;');
  }

  modalContent[2][0].onclick = function() {
    modalContent[2][1].setAttribute('style', 'display: block;');
  }

  modalContent[3][0].onclick = function() {
    modalContent[3][1].setAttribute('style', 'display: block;');
  }

  const modalForEach = () => {
      modal.forEach(element => {
        element.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
    });
  }

  closeModal.forEach(element => {
    element.onclick = function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation(e);
      modalForEach();
    }
  });

  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target === modal[0] || 
        event.target === modal[1] || 
        event.target === modal[2] || 
        event.target === modal[3]) {

      modalForEach();
    }
  }
```